# Iterative outer addition Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, addition

I want to apply outer addition of multiple vectors/matrices. Let's say four times:

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.arange(100)
B = np.add.outer(x,x)
B = np.add.outer(B,x)
B = np.add.outer(B,x)
```

I would like best if the number of additions could be a variable, like `a=4` --> 4 times the addition. Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple loop?   With broadcasting you could do: `x[:,None,None]+x[None,:,None]+x `, but generalizing that to `a` times would be more work.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought it is maybe possible otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with array-initialization -

```
n = 4 # number of iterations to add outer versions
l = len(x)
out = np.zeros([l]*n,dtype=x.dtype)
for i in range(n):
    out += x.reshape(np.insert([1]*(n-1),i,l))
```

**Why this approach and not iterative addition to create new arrays at each iteration?**

Iteratively creating new arrays at each iteration would require more memory and hence memory-overhead there. With array-initialization, we are adding element off `x` into an already initialized array. Hence, it tries to be memory-efficient with it.

**Alternative #1**

We can remove one iteration with initializing with `x`. Hence, the changes would be -

```
out = np.broadcast_to(x,[l]*n).copy()
for i in range(n-1):
```

**Approach # 2: With `np.add.reduce`** -

Another way would be with `np.add.reduce`, which again doesn't create any intermediate arrays, but being a reduction method might be better here as that's what it's implemented for -

```
l = len(x); n = 4
np.add.reduce([x.reshape(np.insert([1]*(n-1),i,l)) for i in range(n)])
```

Timings -

```
In [17]: x = np.arange(100)

In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: n = 4 # number of iterations to add outer versions
    ...: l = len(x)
    ...: out = np.zeros([l]*n,dtype=x.dtype)
    ...: for i in range(n):
    ...:     out += x.reshape(np.insert([1]*(n-1),i,l))
829 ms ± 28.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [19]: l = len(x); n = 4

In [20]: %timeit np.add.reduce([x.reshape(np.insert([1]*(n-1),i,l)) for i in range(n)])
183 ms ± 2.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a builtin argument to repeat this procedure several times, but you can define a custom function for it fairly easily

```py
def recursive_outer_add(arr, num):
    if num == 1:
        return arr

    x = np.add.outer(arr, arr)

    for i in range(num - 1):
        x = np.add.outer(x, arr)
    return x
```

Just as a warning: the array gets really big really fast

Answer (score 1):

Short and reasonably fast:

```
n = 4
l = 10
x = np.arange(l)

sum(np.ix_(*n*(x,)))

timeit(lambda:sum(np.ix_(*n*(x,))),number=1000)
# 0.049082988989539444
```

We can speed this up a little by going back to front:

```
timeit(lambda:sum(reversed(np.ix_(*n*(x,)))),number=1000)
# 0.03847671199764591
```

We can also build our own reversed `np.ix_`:

```
from operator import getitem
from itertools import accumulate,chain,repeat

sum(accumulate(chain((x,),repeat((slice(None),None),n-1)),getitem))

timeit(lambda:sum(accumulate(chain((x,),repeat((slice(None),None),n-1)),getitem)),number=1000)
# 0.02427654700295534
```